# How to create clickable cells in UITableView (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, interactive

I'm working on a personal project and I want to make the cells in my UITableView clickable, such that when they are pressed they segue to the next view, and pass information from their cell along with it when they are pressed.

I've attempted to look over other guides and videos that demonstrate how to do this, however they are all outdated. One that stood out to me that seemed to show promise but didn't end up working was in reference to a certain "didSelectRowAt" function, but I could not get this to work.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as!
    CandidateTableViewCell
    if (indexPath.row >= candidateCells.count){
        print("???")
        candidateCells.append(cell)
        print("Strange error")
    }
    tableView.delegate = self
    cell.CandidateName?.text = candidatesNames[indexPath.item]
    cell.CandidatePos?.text = candidatesPositions[indexPath.item]
    //cell.candidateButton.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.CandidateName.sizeToFit()
    cell.CandidatePos.sizeToFit()
    print(candidateCells)
    print(indexPath.row)
    print(candidateCells.count)
    print(indexPath.row >= candidateCells.count)
    candidateCells[indexPath.item] = cell
    return cell

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "Segue", sender: Any?.self)
}
```

What I was expecting to happen was that the cell would become clickable, and when the cell is clicked it would send me to the next page in the app, however when clicked, nothing happens. The cell does not become highlighted, and the segue does not occur. Thank you so much for any and all suggestions!

Comment: check this https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-pass-data-between-two-view-controllers

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass information to the next cell, I usually avoid using a Segue, and setup the ViewController with a reuse identifier.  By doing this, you can pass information easier.  For instance

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YOURRESUEIDENTIFIER") as! YOURVIEWCONTROLLERCLASS
        vc.infoToPass = cellData[indexPath.row]
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        }

    }
```

Your other option would be to implement the `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier()` method in order to set the data properly.  You would click your cell, which calls the `performSegue` function, which would call the `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` where you can set the data and return `true`